# How can i access the function of contract from different nodes?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am having two contracts say A and B, and two nodes running in different machines Machine1 and Machine 2 with same network id and i had added the peer using node url. Contract A is deployed by machine1 on blockchain, Contract B is deployed by machine2.Now i want access the function of contract A from machine2 and machine 1 and also access the function of contract B from machine2 and machine 1.How can i access the functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate Abi goto https://etherchain.org/solc and place your contract code and get the abi

Use var contract = eth.contract(abi).at(contractaddress)

Replace abi and address with the ABI and address of the contract.

This will allow you to access the contract.

Answer (score 2):

The Ethereum blockchain is a distributed application platform. This means that contract code is not deployed to a specific node; rather, it is deployed to a distributed ledger of which each node has a copy (assuming that each node has reached consensus with the rest of the network). Likewise, when you call a function of a contract, the function call is executed at least on those nodes in your network that are actively mining (validating transactions).

Contracts are created by broadcasting a transaction to the network. Functions on deployed contracts are called also by broadcasting a transaction.

Preparation of the transaction that creates a contract returns the address of the contract. This address references the unique location of the contract on the blockchain; record it. When you send that transaction to the blockchain, wait for the current block to be mined. Once that happens, all nodes should have a copy of the code within a few milliseconds and can then process transactions that call functions in that contract.

Once the contract is created, prepare another transaction that calls a function, referencing as the recipient of the transaction the contract address that you previously recorded. Then, broadcast this transaction to the network. It doesn't matter which node receives the transaction first. Eventually, shortly after the transaction is mined, all nodes in the network will have an updated state of the blockchain that reflects any changes that resulted from the function call.